# Updating transaction amount for an existing order in paytm api

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, payment-gateway, paytm

I've Integrated **paytm API** for payments in my app.I created an Order and initiated a **txn** and completed it. If I want to update the **txnAmount** for that same order, how can I do it? Update Transaction API requires a *txnToken* previously received in the response of Initiate Transaction API. And it's only valid for 15 minutes. I want to update the Order's amount whenever I want. Is there any way to do it? Or Is there any way to reinitiate the transaction with a different **txnAmount**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's now other way to update a initiated transaction. You have to initiate a new transaction every time. [refer here](https://business.paytm.com/docs/all-in-one-sdk/hybrid-apps/cordova?ref=allInOneMerchantIntegration)